# How to separate table by group in SSRS report?

Tags: sql, visual-studio, reporting-services, report, ssrs-2012

I'm working on a project which needs to export a report from `SQL` query using `SSRS`.
The data come from query result (about needs of computer types in each school).

| School | product | specs | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Standford | Desktop | spec1 | 1 |
| Standford | Desktop | spec2 | 2 |
| MIT | Desktop | spec1 | 3 |
| Georgia Tech | Desktop | spec2 | 4 |
| Standford | Laptop | spec3 | 5 |
| Standford | Laptop | spec2 | 6 |
| MIT | Laptop | spec1 | 7 |
| Georgia Tech | Laptop | spec3 | 8 |

**The report we need:**

*Report on Desktop needs*

| School | spec1 | spec2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Standford | 1 | 2 |
| MIT | 3 | 0 |
| Georgia Tech | 0 | 4 |

*Report on Laptop needs*

| School | spec1 | spec2 | spec3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Standford | 0 | 6 | 5 |
| MIT | 7 | 0 | 0 |
| Georgia Tech | 0 | 0 | 8 |

Currently, I am just able to create a report which the `2 tables` are merged into `1`, but I need them to be separated.
Is this possible in `SSRS`, or is there any other way with `SQL` query?

Thank you

Comment: Appreciation to @Arun, which helped me edit my ugly post.

Comment: Do you mean you want a single report but containing a table for each product?

Answer (score 0):

You may try [PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15) in `SQL` to efficiently achieve this:

**Query for Desktop:**

```
SELECT school, 
       COALESCE(spec1,0) AS spec1, 
       COALESCE(spec2,0) AS spec2
FROM t
PIVOT
(
  SUM(Amount)
  FOR specs IN([spec1], [spec2])
) as pvt
WHERE product='desktop'
```

**Query for Laptop:**

```
SELECT school, 
       COALESCE(spec1,0) AS spec1, 
       COALESCE(spec2,0) AS spec2,
       COALESCE(spec3,0) AS spec3
FROM t
PIVOT
(
  SUM(Amount)
  FOR specs IN([spec1], [spec2], [spec3])
) as pvt
WHERE product='laptop'
```

See DEMO in *[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0a81a3824e71ed3f91c36a20600a907f)*

Answer (score 0):

To do this in SSRS, the best way (IMHO) is to create a sub report that takes a single value parameter, in this case `Product` and only shows the data for that one product.

Then create a master report that calls the subreport for available products.

It's a fairly simple process.

In this demo, I've recreated your dataset using a table variable and used the exact same dataset in both the sub-report and the master report.

You'll the following.

The demo dataset query
The creation of the sub report and testing
The creation of the master report, testing the dataset, adding the sub report to the master report
the final results.

The final results will look like this...

[image]

If the GIF below runs too fast, then save it and open it in an image editor so you can step thru it.

[image]